# Reading YAML file with Python results in AttributeError

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to make a script to back up a MySQL database. I have a `config.yml` file:

```
DB_HOST :'localhost'
DB_USER : 'root'
DB_USER_PASSWORD:'P@$$w0rd'
DB_NAME : 'moodle_data'
BACKUP_PATH : '/var/lib/mysql/moodle_data'
```

Now I need to read this file. My Python code so far:

```
import yaml
config = yaml.load(open('config.yml'))
print(config.DB_NAME)
```

And this is an error that comes up:

```
file "conf.py", line 4, in <module>
print(config.DB_NAME)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'DB_NAME'
```

Does anyone have an idea where I made a mistake?

Comment: Welcome to SO btw. The question may be simple, the formatting is good and all useful elements are here. Enjoy your stay, and don't forget to mark an answer as approved when your question is fully answered :)

Comment: You should not be using `yaml.load()` as it can be unsafe and from your question it looks like you don't have the experience to judge correctly if you are affected or not (use `.safeload()` instead). Your code also has a problem if reading `config.yml` throws an error (while parsing), in that case your file might not be closed properly. You should use the `with` statement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- As others have said, yaml.load() loads associative arrays as mappings, so you need to use `config['DB_NAME']`.
- The syntax in your config file is not correct: in YAML, keys are separated from values by a colon+space.

Should work if the file is formatted like this:

```
DB_HOST: 'localhost'
DB_USER: 'root'
DB_USER_PASSWORD: 'P@$$w0rd'
DB_NAME: 'moodle_data'
BACKUP_PATH: '/var/lib/mysql/moodle_data'
```

Answer (score 2):

**To backup your data base**, you should be able to export it as a `.sql` file. If you're using a specific interface, look for `Export`.

Then, for Python's yaml parser.

```
DB_HOST :'localhost'
DB_USER : 'root'
DB_USER_PASSWORD:'P@$$w0rd'
DB_NAME : 'moodle_data'
BACKUP_PATH : '/var/lib/mysql/moodle_data'
```

is a `key-value` thing (sorry, didn't find a better word for that one). In certain langage (such as PHP I think), they are converted to *objects*. In python though, they are converted to *dicts* (yaml parser does it, JSON parser  too).

```
# access an object's attribute
my_obj.attribute = 'something cool'
my_obj.attribute # something cool
del my_obj.attribute
my_obj.attribute # error

# access a dict's key's value
my_dict = {}
my_dict['hello'] = 'world!'
my_dict['hello'] # world!
del my_dict['hello']
my_dict['hello'] # error
```

So, that's a really quick presentation of dicts, but that should you get you going (run `help(dict)`, and/or have a look [here](http://devdocs.io#q=python%20dict.) you won't regret it)

In your case:

```
config['DB_NAME'] # moodle_data
```

Comment: “JSON compiler” does not really make sense as parsing a JSON document produces a data structure, not a program. I suppose you meant JSON parser, and more specifically, python's default json parser. Good point insisting on using [the correct tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) for db backup btw.

Comment: Whoops... Thanks, fixed it!

Comment: import yaml
config=yaml.load(open('config.yml'))
db=config['DB_NAME']
print db    still TypeError comes up "string indices must be integers, not str"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import yaml
with open('config.yaml', 'r') as f:
    doc = yaml.load(f)
```

To access "DB_NAME" you can use:

```
txt = doc["DB_NAME"]
print txt
```

Comment: it says TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Most likely do: doc[0]['DB_NAME'], cause reasons.