# How to use if-else condition on gitlabci

Tags: if-statement, gitlab-ci

How to use if else condition inside the gitlab-CI.

I have below code:

```
deploy-dev:
  image: testimage
  environment: dev
  tags:
    - kubectl
  script:
   - kubectl apply -f demo1 --record=true
   - kubectl apply -f demo2 --record=true
```

Now I want to add a condition something like this

```
script:
    - (if [ "$flag" == "true" ]; then kubectl apply -f demo1 --record=true; else kubectl apply -f demo2 --record=true);
```

Could someone provide the correct syntax for the same? Is there any documentation for the conditions (if-else, for loop) in gitlabci?

Comment: Why did you put brackets around the `if` line?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Hereunder three syntax options for that kind of statement. From gitlab-ci [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml) :

#### Using shell variable

```
deploy-dev:
image: testimage
environment: dev
tags:
 - kubectl
script:
 - if [ "$flag" == "true" ]; then MODULE="demo1"; else MODULE="demo2"; fi
 - kubectl apply -f ${MODULE} --record=true
```

#### Using shell variable with yaml multiline block

```
deploy-dev:
image: testimage
environment: dev
tags:
  - kubectl
script:
  - >
    if [ "$flag" == "true" ]; then
      kubectl apply -f demo1 --record=true
    else
      kubectl apply -f demo2 --record=true
    fi
```

#### Using gitlab rules

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

#### Using gitlab templates and variables

```
demo1-deploy-dev:
  extends: .deploy-dev
  only:
    variables: [ $flag == "true" ]
  variables:
    MODULE: demo1
        
demo2-deploy-dev:
  extends: .deploy-dev
  only:
    variables: [ $flag == "false" ]
  variables:
    MODULE: demo2
        
.deploy-dev:
image: testimage
environment: dev
tags:
  - kubectl
script:
  - kubectl apply -f ${MODULE} --record=true
```

Comment: In the last example how you check the value of $flag?

Comment: @RogerCollAumatell : i.e. Using `only: variables: [ $flag == "true" ]`

Comment: @XavierD: I'm not able to grok the last example. It looks like a variable is being set for MODULE, which is used in .deploy-dev, which is based on $flag, but what causes .deploy-dev to be run at all? (I thought the '.' prefix meant that the section was skipped (hidden)?

Comment: Thanks @Cognitiaclaeves. Indeed `extends` keyword was missing from jobs definitions. You're right, the '.' prefixed job is not executed and acts as a template or let's say an abstract job here. I've fixed my example. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: there is also `- |` which is similar to `- >` only that it will keep the content multiline instead of concatenating it into a single line interspersed with `;`

Answer (score 39):

Note that with [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#cicd-rulesif-support-logical-expressions-with-parentheses) (August 2020), there is an improvement to the if-else rule syntax:

> ### CI/CD rules:if support logical expressions with parentheses
>
> **If** you use the `rules` keyword with `if` clauses, it’s now even more powerful, with support for bracketed expressions evaluated by the pipeline processor.
>
> You can use more complex and efficient AND (`&&`) / OR (`||`) expressions, making your pipelines rules more logical, powerful, and easier to manage.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/230938).

---

And, with [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#support-variables-for-pipeline-rules) (January 2021)

> ### Support variables for pipeline rules
>
> Previously, the `rules` keyword was limited in scope and only determined if a job should be included or excluded from pipelines. In this release, you can now decide if certain conditions are met and subsequently override variables in jobs, providing you with more flexibility when configuring your pipelines.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_8/var.png -- Support variables for pipeline rules]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesvariables) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209864).

---

With [GitLab 13.12](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#support-variables-in-cicd-pipeline-workflowrules) (May 2021):

> ### Support variables in CI/CD pipeline 'workflow:rules'
>
> Previously, the `rules` keyword was limited in scope and only determined if a job should be included or excluded from pipelines. [In 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#support-variables-for-pipeline-rules), we added the ability to use the `variables` keyword with `rules` to set variable values in a job based on which rule matched.
>
> In this release we’ve extended this ability to `workflow: rules`, so you can set variable values for the whole pipeline if certain conditions match.
> This helps you make your pipelines even more flexible.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_12/variable.png -- Support variables in CI/CD pipeline 'workflow:rules']
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrulesvariables) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/294232).

---

> How do you check if a variable is empty?
> When a commit is a tag instead of a branch, the `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` variable is empty. But I'm using that built-in variable down the pipeline. If it's empty, then everything else fails.

In order to handle a scenario where a variable may be empty or undefined, and to prevent subsequent steps in your pipeline from failing, you can use shell scripting techniques within the `script` section of your GitLab CI/CD job definitions.
In the context of checking if the `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` variable is empty, you can use an if-else statement in a shell script.

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - |
      if [ -z "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" ]; then
        echo "The CI_COMMIT_BRANCH variable is empty or undefined."
        # Set the variable to a default value or take other necessary actions
        export CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=default_value
      else
        echo "The CI_COMMIT_BRANCH variable is set to $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH."
        # Continue with the rest of your script
      fi
```

- The `-z` operator is used to check if `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is empty or undefined.
- If `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is empty or undefined, a message is printed to the console, and `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is set to a default value using the `export` command. You can replace `default_value` with a value that makes sense for your pipeline, or you could implement other logic to handle this scenario as needed.
- If `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is not empty, a message is printed to the console indicating its value, and the script proceeds to execute the rest of your commands.

That way, you make sure the `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` variable has a value before proceeding with the rest of your pipeline, which should prevent subsequent steps from failing due to an empty or undefined `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` variable.

Comment: How do you check if a variable is empty?  When a commit is a tag instead of a branch, the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH variable is empty.  But I'm using that built-in variable down the pipeline.  If it's empty then everything else fails.

Comment: @tzg I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 11):

In addition, in the case of a multiline block if you want or need to preserve line breaks you can use the pipe character:

```
script: |
    if [ "$flag" == "true" ]; then
      kubectl apply -f demo1 --record=true
    else
      kubectl apply -f demo2 --record=true
    fi
```

To go deeper, visit https://yaml-multiline.info/

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to just add a semicolon and closing "fi" at the end. 
I couldn't find a link to documentation.

```
script:
    - (if [ "$flag" == "true" ]; then kubectl apply -f demo1 --record=true; else kubectl apply -f demo2 --record=true; fi);
```

Answer (score 4):

You may consider checking [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)

It allows for a list of individual rule objects to be evaluated in order, until one matches and dynamically provides attributes to the job.

Available rule clauses include:

- if (similar to only:variables)
- changes (same as only:changes)
- exists

Example:

```
job:
  script: "echo Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
      when: always
    - if: '$VAR =~ /pattern/'
      when: manual
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: Using =~ pattern matching is really useful. Just be aware of the limitations of this regex pattern matching if you decide to use the pattern in a variable: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35438

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when using `powershell` based gitlab scripts:

```
script:
  - 'if ($flag -eq "true") { kubectl apply -f demo1 --record=true; } else { kubectl apply -f demo2 --record=true; }'
```