# Why my comparison in Gitlab CI doesn't work

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

Very confused on why this job is added to the pipeline, despite the condition being not satisfied:

```
rules:
  - if: $COMMIT_HASH != "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```

The $COMMIT_HASH takes the default value of $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA and when I troubleshot this on the script, I found that that they are indeed identical:

```
echo "COMMIT_HASH is $COMMIT_HASH and CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA is $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```

and I got:

```
COMMIT_HASH is 60a1ee54 and CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA is 60a1ee54
```

I feel like this is a double quote thing or something.
Any help please ?

Comment: Why quote `"$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"` but not `$COMMIT_HASH`? I know nothing of Gitlab CI, but I'd guess you should either quote both or neither.

Comment: I ended up doing this because of VS Code marking it as invalid when I quote both and it goes like this: Unexpected tag at node endYAML
Unexpected double-quoted-scalar at node end

Comment: Ugh, Yaml is just a a dream like that. Way too much flexibility that's not obvious ... still: try not quoting either one.

Comment: `COMMIT_HASH` is not a builtin variable. Where/how are you defining this variable? It's possible you're defining this variable in a place or manner that is not supported for `rules:` evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps flip your logic. c.f. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761464/how-to-use-if-else-condition-on-gitlabci) for a variety of possible approaches.

Also, try single-quoting your entire condition.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '"$COMMIT_HASH" == "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```