# Is there a way to apply conditions in yaml file and run in scala by reading from yaml? Provide a simple example of same file yaml

Tags: scala, if-statement, yaml, conditional-statements, encapsulation

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use yaml file for conditional statements like if else.
What I want to achieve is to put my conditions in yaml file and use the file in the scala program. When the function is run, it will read the yaml file which inturn will have the conditions to perform. This is to be done in order to cater any changes in the conditions in the future. So in future, if any change in condition happen, it can be catered from yaml and keeping all other code un touched.

Is there any possible way!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If condition possible in yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194104/if-condition-possible-in-yaml-file)

Comment: NO, it doesn't answer my question. I only want a basic example to get started with in order to understand how conditions work in yaml. It can be in the same yaml like if varA=varB then varC else "nothing found". All in same yaml. Later i will see how to get value from other yaml